# create viewer SVF in design automation

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

So I've been looking into whether it's possible to create an SVF file straight out of design automation so whenever you update the model, you don't have to do another roundtrip through model derivative to view it. It looks like it is possible from [This sample](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/design.automation-custom-data-viewer), is there any better documentation around this?

Answer (score 1):

Ah I found something that should work relatively well (other than having the source to their extraction), it's hidden somewhere in the [design automation field guide examples](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/field-guide/)!
So you can use those special design automation AutoCad commands to do these tasks.
_prepareforpropertyextraction
_indexextractor
_publishtosvf
_createbubblepackage

`"(command \"_prepareforpropertyextraction\" \"index.json\")\n(command \"_indexextractor\" \"index.json\")\n(command \"_publishtosvf\" \"./output/result.svf\")\n(command \"_createbubblepackage\" \"./output\" \"./result\" \"\" \"\")\n"`

full sample

`{
    "commandLine": [
        "$(engine.path)\\accoreconsole.exe /i $(args[HostDwg].path) /al $(appbundles[Publish2View22].path) /s $(settings[script].path)"
    ],
    "parameters": {
        "HostDwg": {
            "verb": "get",
            "description": "Host drawing",
            "localName": "$(EmptyDwg)"
        },
        "Result": {
            "zip": true,
            "verb": "post",
            "description": "Results",
            "localName": "result"
        }
    },
    "engine": "Autodesk.AutoCAD+22",
    "appbundles": [
        "AutoCAD.Publish2View22+prod"
    ],
    "settings": {
        "script": "(command \"_prepareforpropertyextraction\" \"index.json\")\n(command \"_indexextractor\" \"index.json\")\n(command \"_publishtosvf\" \"./output/result.svf\")\n(command \"_createbubblepackage\" \"./output\" \"./result\" \"\" \"\")\n"
    },
    "description": "AutoCAD translation sample generating SVF via core console.",
    "version": 1,
    "id": "AutoCAD.AcSvfPublish+prod"
}`

Makes sense, I would be surprised if model derivative API didn't use design automation API behind the scenes to process the models.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Design Automation service itself does not exactly provide such capabilities.

Not sure if there's any sample code for this approach but you can totally get a callback (see [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/callbacks/) for details) from the Design Automation service to your backend and then call the Model Derivative service in the plugin to start a SVF translation job in your backend - your backend can be as simple, cloud native as a serverless function.

Don't think though it'd work if you try to make the http calls in your plugin because our cloud engines themselves might have the necessary network access to fulfil the requests - haven't really verified that myself so feel free to give that a go.